# jquery keyup function: enabling/disabling a textbox using keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable the textbox using keyup functionality. I have a **TextArea** and a **Text Box**. Now i use a keyup operation on backspace key, like if the length of content inside textarea is 3 it should disable the textbox. I also have an alert message which pops when the length of content in text area is 3. Code worked for the pop up but it doesnot worked for the textbox. What am i missing? Please help. Here is my code:

```
$('#comment').keyup(function() {
    if (event.which == 8) {
           var txt = $('#comment').val().length;
            if(txt == 3)
            {
                alert("backspace");
                $("#text1").attr("diasbled", "diasbled");
            }
        }

});
```

And here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgY43/) for the purpose.

Comment: such a silly mistake i have done. Thank you guys. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some typo here it should be `disabled` not `diasbled`
Try this

```
$('#comment').keyup(function () {
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    if (len >= 3) {
        $("#text1").prop("disabled", true);
    }
    else{
     $("#text1").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mgY43/4/)

Comment: if i want to do the same on backspace event then how to do it. can you please explain me that too.

Comment: No need to handle backspace here, just put the else condition, see my updated answer

Comment: if u are using version earlier than Jquery 1.6 then You will have to use  .attr (like  $("#text1").attr("disabled", true);) instead of .prop 
@nrsharma am i right ??

Answer (score 3):

You need to do:

1) `this.value.length` to get the total characters length of your textarea

2) From jQuery version `1.6` , use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** instead of `.attr()` to set the properties of an element

3) Correct the typo: it should be `disabled` not `diasbled`

```
$('#comment').keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length >= 3) {
        $("#text1").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("#text1").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgY43/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop` instead of `attr` also pass event to function

```
 $('#comment').keyup(function (event) { //and event here
    if (event.which == 8) {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 3) {
            $("#text1").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.. but you mispelled the "disabled" in your code. Here's the sample..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>js test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="" id="comment" />
<input type="text" value="" id="text1" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#comment').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 8) {
               var txt = $('#comment').val().length;
                if(txt == 3)
                {
                    alert("backspace");
                    $("#text1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            }

    });
});
</script>
</body>
```